# Как на Bitbucket.org добавить второе рабочее место? (Для записи в репозитарий)

Tags: bitbucket, git

Есть проект на Butbucket (приватный). До недавнего времени использовал Bitbucket практически как резервоное копирование, соединяясь с одного рабочего места.

Теперь мне нужно добавить второй компьютер, с которого я работаю. И сделать возможность пушить изменения.

На втором рабочем месте я сгенерировал пару открытый-закрытый ключ, открытый добавил в «Settings»-«Ключи развертывания». Но там написано следующее: «Используйте ключи развертывания для получения доступа на чтение к этому репозиторию». То есть, пушить со второго рабочего места не могу. Git говорит следующее:

```
> git push
conq: repository access denied. access via a deployment key is read-only.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

На вкладке «Settings»-«Управление доступом» есть только один пользователь, который создался при создании репозитария, и под которым я могу работать с первого рабочего места. На втором рабочем месте у меня настоен тот же самый логин и емайл пользователя (ведь я тот же самый человек). Но со второго рабочего места пушить не могу. Вот здесь нашел совет:

> http://friendfeed.com/bessarabov/619035bd/email?embed=1
>
> Чтобы дать доступ к приватному
> репозиторию, нужно указать email
> человека, а не его логин на битбакете.

Решил в управлении доступом сделать вторую запись, но указать не логин (который уже там есть), а емайл. В результате битбакет показывает ошибку:

```
{«error»: {«message»: «'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-1: ordinal not in range(128)», «detail»: " File \«/opt/python/domains/bitbucket.org/current/bitbucket/local/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/piston/resource.py\», line 208, in __call__\n result = checked_meth(request, *args, **kwargs)\n File \«/opt/python/domains/bitbucket.org/current/bitbucket/local/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/piston/resource.py\», line 195, in checked_meth\n return meth(*args, **kwargs)\n File \«/opt/python/domains/bitbucket.org/current/bitbucket/local/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/newrelic-2.18.1.15/newrelic/hooks/component_piston.py\», line 33, in __call__\n return self._nr_wrapped(*args, **kwargs)\n File \«/opt/python/domains/bitbucket.org/2014-05-07/bitbucket/../bitbucket/apps/bb/decorators.py\», line 38, in wrap\n return f(request, *a, **kwa)\n File \«/opt/python/domains/bitbucket.org/2014-05-07/bitbucket/../bitbucket/apps/api/v10/decorators.py\», line 386, in wrapper\n resp.content = str(e)\n", «id»: «b46672c0ff36478e9140bc8bd8a47cbd»}}
```

Я что-то вообще туплю. Такое простое действие, как добавить второе рабочее место, не могу сделать. Помогите плз.

Comment: > открытый добавил в «Settings»-«Ключи развертывания».

Прямым текстом написано, что это такое. Зачем пихать туда что ни попадя?

Вам в account - user - security - ssh keys. SSH ключ представляет пользователя (не имеет к конкретной репе никакого отношения!), права на репы контролируются самим битбакетом. Deployment keys - это совсем другое.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В общем, искал настройки не там. Оказывается, настройки аккаунта находятся не в `Settings`, а отдельно (клик на аватар, выбрать `Управление аккаунтом`). Там в разделе `SSH ключи` надо добавить новый ключ. Ключ в разделе `Settings` - `Ключи развертывания` надо предварительно удалить, а то система не даст добавить новый ключ.

Но багрепорт надо запилить. У них раскрытие пути прямым текстом, и никого не волнует, что удивительно.